# Fundamentals relating to Rails 3.x Assocations where a foreign key exists in both tables of the relationship and belongs_to autosave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, rails-activerecord

What is the best way to implement associations in models for the following tables relationships.

#### Current Details / Objectives

- Keep table structure the same, since it's a legacy database.
- I want to have the option to save the `User` and their `primary address` in one swoop.
- `users` table has a `primaryaddressid` column which points to a `user_addresses`.`addressid` table.
- `user_addresses` table has a foreign key of `userid` that points to `users`.`userid`

#### Here is what I have so far.

```
# User model class associations
has_many :user_addresses, :foreign_key => "userid", :autosave => true
belongs_to :primary_address, :class_name => "UserAddress", :foreign_key => "primaryaddressid", :autosave => true
```

And I would like to be able to optionally create the user with the primary address such as...

```
User.new
User.primary_address.build(:street => 'dfkslf', :street2 => 'dfjkslfjlks231', etc)
User.save
```

And this would then save the record as well as update the primaryaddressid of the User table automatically.

#### The question...

I'm thinking my main option is create an `after_save` that verifies if `primaryaddressid` has a value, if not, look in `user_addresses` for a latest address that was inserted given the `userid` and add the `addressid` to the user and update it.

What is the best way to handle this situation to allow me the most flexibility with adding my User and with minimal performance hits?

Answer (score 1):

So I've found my solution that I'm somewhat happy with.

In my `UserAddress` model I added:

```
attr_writer :is_primary
attr_reader :is_primary

after_save :update_primaryid

def set_as_primary!
  self.is_primary = true
end

def update_primaryid
  if self.is_primary
     user = User.find_by_personid(self.personid)
     user.primaryaddressid = self.addressid
     user.save!
  end
end
```

Which allows me the liberty to do:

```
useraddress = user.user_addresses.build(personAddr)
useraddress.set_as_primary!

user.save!
```